# How to get value Unity3D InputField GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So how can I get the value of the text that is inside the Input field (textbox) or Unity3D

Here is what I tried in c#

```
public void UserInput (string UserInput)
{
    UserName = UserInput;
}

public void PassInput (string PassInput)
{
    Password = PassInput;
}
```

In Unity I put this. http://gyazo.com/b90e2d05b806b0fde90122e7a2302463

Please Help. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're not actually calling the InputField. The correct way to get that value would be

```
public void UserInput(InputField userField)
{
    string username = userField.text;
}

public void PassInput (InputField passField)
{
    string password = passField.text;
}
```

Of course like this you have to pass the [InputField](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html) as a parameter, if you only need this method to assign a value to a string you could just pass the InputField.text as a parameter.

To make your setup work, you have to assign "Scripts" to an object and drag that object in the editor (where you dragged Scripts). You also have to modify slightly your functions, like this:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
[SerializeField] private InputField _userField;
[SerializeField] private InputField _passField;

// Other code.

public void UserInput()
{
    string username = _userField.text;
    // Code that uses the username variable.
}

public void PassInput ()
{
    string password = _passField.text;
    // Code that uses the password variable.
}
```

This way you can actually drag the InputFields from the scene hierarchy to the "Scripts" object directly in the editor.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Put more succinctly, to access to the Text sub-gameobject of InputText, you have to access the text var of InputText

Example

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public InputText inputtext; 

void Start(){
   inputtext.text = "replaced";
}
```

Assign inputtext by dragging an instance of the input field you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use: inputField.text, inputField.value

Comment: yep, verified - .text does not maintain assignment for inputfield